# Embedding RSS feed into HTML email?

Tags: javascript, html, email, rss

I'm having problems embedding the following RSS feed into an HTML email, it does not display, any ideas how to overcome this problem?

```
<!-- start feedwind code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function() {
   var params = {rssmikle_url: "http://feed.mikle.com/support/rss/|http://www.northernirelandchamber.com/",
   rssmikle_frame_width: "300",rssmikle_frame_height: "400",rssmikle_target: "_blank",
   rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",
   responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "off",
   autoscroll: "on",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "20",sort: "New",
   rssmikle_title: "on",rssmikle_title_sentence: "",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",
   rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
   rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",
   rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "on",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",
   rssmikle_item_description_tag: "off",rssmikle_item_description_image_scaling: "off",article_num: "15",
   rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script>
   <div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:300;">
       <a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a>
       <!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.-->
  </div><!-- end feedwind code -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe http: before the link ?

```
src="http://feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"
```